# I wanna make node process wait for response

Tags: node.js

I make scraper using the nightmare module.
but a site scraped checks a bot with capcha

my solution is that a node process give a chapcha image to frontend.
and then I give a value of capcha from front to existing node process.

but I have a problem.
I can't find how node process maintains.

Do you know a node module for maintainning node process?
or Is there any solution?

This is backend Soruce.

```
io.on('connection', function(client){
    client.on('event', function(data){});
    client.on('disconnect', function(){});

    client.on('test2', function(value){
        console.log("aaa");
        nightmare
            .goto("http://naver.com")
            .wait(1000)
            .end()
    });

    client.on('test', function(val){

        console.log(nightmare);

        nightmare
            .goto("https://www.amazon.de/")
            .evaluate(() => document.querySelector('body').innerHTML)
            .then(function (html) {
                console.log("wait");
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.error(error,'Promise error');
            });

    });
});
```

and this is a frontend source.

```
methods: {
      test: function() {
          this.$socket.emit('test');
      },
        test2: function() {
            this.$socket.emit('test2');
        }
```

Comment: Can you post your code so far?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by maintaining node process ? Is it like you want to see how many node process is running or pragmatically get those ?

Comment: I add sources, when I use test method test websocket runs but I don't end nightmare and then I use test2 method but nightmare can't working.